# get data from external documents

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below xml files

XML1:

```
<chapter num="01">
<title><page num="1"/><content-style font-style="bold">INTRODUCTION</content-style></title>
<chapter-meta><author><name><firstname>YEO</firstname><middlename>HWEE</middlename><surname>YING</surname></name></author></chapter-meta>
</chapter>
```

XML2:

```
<chapter num="02">
<title><page num="35"/><content-style font-style="bold">INCORPORATION AND ITS CONSEQUENCES</content-style></title>
<chapter-meta><author><name><firstname>TAN</firstname><middlename>CHENG</middlename><surname>HAN</surname></name></author></chapter-meta>
</chapter>
```

XML3:

```
<chapter num="03">
<title><page num="78"/><page num="79"/><content-style font-style="bold">CORPORATE PERSONALITY</content-style></title>
<chapter-meta><author><name><firstname>TAN</firstname><middlename>CHENG</middlename><surname>HAN</surname></name></author></chapter-meta>
</chapter>
```

and the main XML file is

```
<main>
<toc-item>
<toc-title>CHAPTER 1 INTRODUCTION</toc-title>
</toc-item>
<toc-item>
<toc-title>CHAPTER 2 INCORPORATION AND ITS CONSEQUENCES</toc-title>
</toc-item>
<toc-item>
<toc-title>CHAPTER 3 CORPORATE PERSONALITY</toc-title>
</toc-item>
</main>
```

here i need to compare the chapter numbers with the chapter number in the xml files (xml1, xml2, xml3) and display the author name. The expected output is as below.

```
Chapter 1: YEO HWEE YING
Chapter 2: TAN CHENG HAN
Chapter 3: TAN CHENG HAN
```

I've tried the below code.

```
  <xsl:variable name="pg">
                                     <xsl:value-of select="document('C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\Proview\SG\Commentary_SG_XML-03032014\SG-Walter Woon on Company Law (3rd ed)/title.xml')/entry/file/translate(translate(./@name,'Walter Woon on Company Law (3rd ed)_Chapter',''),'.x  ','')"/>                                                                              </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$Chapn=$pg"/>
```

here i have crated an XML file with all the chapter names and took that in the document element. here when i try to print the output, it is showing me `false`.

please let me know how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Please, also include the definition of variable `$Chapn` and re-indent your XSLT code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most XSLT 2.0 processors you can use the `collection` function to access a collection of files from the file system but the concrete syntax depends on the XSLT processor. With Saxon 9 the following works for me:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="chapters" select="collection('.?select=XML*.xml')/chapter"/>

<xsl:template match="toc-item/toc-title">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="chapter\s+([0-9]+)\s+" flags="i">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$chapters[xs:integer(@num) eq xs:integer(regex-group(1))]/chapter-meta/author/name/*"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With your three files `XML1.xml`, `XML2.xml`, `XML3.xml` in the same working directory as the main input the output then is

```
CHAPTER 1 YEO HWEE YING
CHAPTER 2 TAN CHENG HAN
CHAPTER 3 TAN CHENG HAN
```

With the version 2013 of AltovaXML the following works for me:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="chapters" select="collection('./XML*.xml')/chapter"/>

<xsl:template match="toc-item/toc-title">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="chapter\s+([0-9]+)\s+" flags="i">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$chapters[xs:integer(@num) eq xs:integer(regex-group(1))]/chapter-meta/author/name/*"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't know whether that use of `collection` works with the latest version called Raptor of Altova's XSLT engine, I don't have access to that as they don't provide a developer release or license anymore and http://manual.altova.com/RaptorXML/raptorxmlserver/ does not seem to contain a documentation of the use of `collection`, at least on quick browsing.

Comment: Hi @Martin Thanks for the code, but this is not working in native Altova XML Spy processor, can you please let me know how to use colections without use of SAXON. Thanks

Comment: @user2423959, I have provided a sample for AltovaXML, the XSLT processor Altova provided until 2013. I don't know whether RaptorXML, their latest XSLT processor, is compatible.

Comment: Hi @Martin, I've came across another similar issue, unable figure it how to proceed can you please help me. the question is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489118/get-the-child-from-different-documents) Thanks